# ggplot - altering the height of each overlapping variable on a density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm quite new to R and ggplot2 so apologies if this is an obvious question, but I've searched around and can't find anything about this exact issue

I have a ggplot density plot for 6 variables on the same plot, overlapping. What I am trying to do is *to change the maximum height of each variable to be a certain value without changing the distribution*. e.g. :

```
variable_1 - 1, //on Y axis
variable_2 - 0.5 etc.
```

This way I can get an idea of the distribution (across the x axis) whilst also showing a second independent parameter through the y axis

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible although I wouldn't recommend it. What you can do is just divide the distribution by it's maximum and then multiply with the target height.

```
# some example data:
x = seq(-5, 5, .1)
y1 = dnorm(x)
y2 = dnorm(x, .5, .2)
Y = cbind(y1, y2)
matplot(x, Y, type = 'l', bty = 'n', lty = 1, las = 1)

# now I want the red line to be max 1
# and the black line to be mack .5
y1 = .5*y1 / max(y1)
y2 = 1*y2 / max(y2)
Y = cbind(y1, y2)
matplot(x, Y, type = 'l', bty = 'n', lty = 1, las = 1)
```

The important part here is that I used two different transformations for `y1` and `y2`. The consequence is that in the second figure the distributions cannot be compared anymore. You can avoid this by only applying the same transformation to all distributions.